# How to scan by ColumnPrefixFilter with SingleColumnValueFilter and get all columns?

Tags: java, hbase, database-scan

We have hbase table and I need to scan through it. I have to find all rows where one particular column has exact value and exists other column with exact prefix.
Something like:

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filterA =
                new SingleColumnValueFilter(COLUMN_FAMILY, COLUMN_1, CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(2L));
Filter filterB = new ColumnPrefixFilter(COLUMN_2_PREFIX);

FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
filterList.addFilter(filterA);
filterList.addFilter(filterB);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filterList);
```

Individually filters work perfect. `filterA` returns rows where `COLUMN_1` has the value `2L`. `filterB` returns rows where `COLUMN_2` exists. But together they return nothing. 
So can I combine this filters together? Or I do smth wrong?

Second question with the same condition: can I use `ColumnPrefixFilter` and get all columns. I mean to find rows where `COLUMN_2` exists and get all other columns too?

Comment: probably a stupid question but have you verified that you do actually have rows that satisfy both conditions together ? (unless you wanted an OR operation and then you should change the operator to MUST_PASS_ONE)

Comment: Yes, of course. There are rows that satisfy both conditions. I suspect `ColumnPrefixFilter` doesn't want to work with other columns in filters. Because, if to change `filterA` to filter value into the `COLUMN_2` column, the code works well.

Answer (score 1):

I found partly decision. I can use `QualifierFilter` instead of `ColumnPrefixFilter`. And it works:

```
Filter filterB = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(COLUMN_2_PREFIX));
```

I get rows with one column `COLUMN_2`. But I still strongly need to get all columns, not only one I filtered by.